# How to migrate to a new SVN repository (from an existing one)?

Tags: svn, subclipse

We have code in a SVN repository and is accessed through Subclipse Plugin in eclipse.   I want to switch to a new SVN repository.  How can I do that?

Note: I dont have access to command line tools.

Answer (score 1):

if that repositery is on a different workplace then -

```
file -> switch workplace
```

if you want to make a new svn repository then use

```
windows->open prespective->SVN repositery exploring
```

then right click and `New`